# Custom Fields are not showing when trying to import a CSV

Tags: custom-fields, import, data-import

I have created some custom fields. I am trying to import contacts with values for those fields. But the fields are not showing up during the step 2 "matching civicrm field"  though other custom fields that I have created shows up, this one particular doesn't show up. I have allowed multiple records for this one custom field set alone. Is that because of this?

On further testing, when I disallowed multiple records for this set, it shows up in the matching options. Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-value custom fields need to be imported separately using https://yoursite/civicrm/import/custom?reset=1

To find that link, go to the normal contact import screen `Contacts > Import Contacts`, click the help icon at the end of the helptext, then follow the link at the end of the pop-up help.