# Fields not showing in Matching CiviCRM Field drop down list

Tags: custom-fields, import

hope someone can help with this.
We have created a Custom Field set called Shareholder.  These fields have been used when adding new shareholders one by one.  I would now like to use a CSV file to import contact information for our existing shareholders.  But when I try to do this, the fields in the Shareholder set do not appear in the Matching CiviCRM Field drop down list.  How do I get them to appear?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the custom field set a repeating field set?  If so the import for repeating field sets used to be found by going to the regular import screen, and clicking a link there. However since 5.51 when importing was overhauled I'm not sure what the situation is.

Comment: See this answer for more specifics, of it is a repeating custom field set https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19089/custom-fields-are-not-showing-when-trying-to-import-a-csv?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Andy. The field set is not a repeating field set.  Should it be? Reading the link above suggests that to do this, I would need to start again as the flag can only be set on an empty set, so am reluctant to do this if it's not the answer.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a repeating field set, I was just guessing that was the problem you were having as that import was somewhat hidden.  As it's not repeating, you should see the matching fields on import, which will be preceded by the custom field set name plus ::